# SQL Use stored procedure to insert date from excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm trying to use a stored procedure : ie "EXECUTE SetName @name"

But the parameters need to be from an Excel table

---

### |A|

### NAME

- JOHNS
- PATRICK
- JAMES
- JEAN
- ASHLEY

I tried some tutorials on YouTube but it was only for selecting table.

Or an alternative is to do a while loop on the excel's column.

Thanks for helping ^^

Comment: Write an Excel formula that generates the execute statement (string) you need using column references. Apply that to all rows. Copy and paste the resulting set of strings into a SSMS query window. Then execute those statements.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you show me an example ? i used excel long time ago ... thanks for the answer.